# Angular 2 rxjs subscribe is not a function when getting data from service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm new to angular and I know this is a basic but I'm having problems passing the `_newArray` to my child component using a shared service

**Service**

```js
getJson(): Observable < any > {
  return forkJoin(this.getQuestions(), this.getData()).pipe(
    tap(data => {
      this.MergeData(this._questionsArray, this._dataArray);
    })
  );
}

MergeData(question, data): any[]{
  let _newArray: any[] = [];
  _newArray.push({
    test1: "test1",
    test2: "test2"
  });
  return _newArray
}
```

**Component**

```js
export class CheckComponent implements OnInit {

  _finalArr: any[];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiService.getJson()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this._finalArr = data;
      });

  }
}
```

Comment: You subscribe both inside `getJson` and after calling `getJson` inside `ngOnInit`. You should only subscribe once at the end of your pipe.

Comment: You have another issue that `MergeData` doesn't return anything. Possibly you want to return the new array there, and replace the `subscribe` inside `getJson` with a `map` operator for example.

Comment: Also `forkJoin` in your case will return an `Observable<[question, data]>`. So your `data` inside subscribe is actually an array of those two values.

Comment: what if I just want to return the merged data only? I edited the code

Comment: I already told you to use `map`. You used `tap`. Tap is for side effects and only modifies the element it receives. `map` allows you to transform the data and let you return the new element.

Comment: When you use `map`, you will have to write `return this.MergeData(...)`

Comment: Thanks! got it by using const combined = forkJoin(this.getQuestions(), this.getData())
    
       return combined.pipe(map(newValues=> {
          return this.MergeData(this._questionsArray, this._dataArray);
       }))

Comment: but now I'm having hard time getting an object of json and storing to component from a web service
getQuestions(): Observable<any>{
   //For WebService Questions
  return this.http
  .get('../assets/samplequestion.json').pipe(
    map(response => {
      this._questionsArray = response.json();
      
    }),catchError(this.handleError));
    
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getJson` is currently returning a Subscription, it must return an Observable. Try:

```
getJson(): Observable {

    return forkJoin(this.getQuestions(), this.getData()).pipe(
      tap(data => {
          this.MergeData(this._questionsArray, this._dataArray);
      })
    );
  }
```